# cakePHP getting data from model with a condition (after specific date)

Tags: php, cakephp, request, pagination

I want to get information from database using a condition which is got from GET request.

Model

```
id | title | date
```

Get request is:

```
$frutherthan = $this->request->query('furtherthan');
```

now how to get the data from model where date is further than $furtherthan?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to create your find in your controller and pass your `$furtherthan` variable into it.

```
$this->Model->find( 'list', array( 
    'conditions' => array( 
        'Model.date >=' => $furtherthan 
     ) 
) );
```

This will return a list (id and display field) for the records that match the condition. You may have to alter the actual SQL slightly, but this should get you started. you can find out more in the cookbook.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions

Comment: can $furtherthan be in '2013-07-31 00:00:00' format? if date in model is ?